# AWs lambda - enable events in slack fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-api

I created an AWS Lambda function with the following default (Hello world example) code.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I also added an API gateway as a trigger and when tested with curl, I can successfully retrieve the 'Hello from Lambda Message'

```
curl https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/test
"Hello from Lambda!"
```

Then, as I want to build a slackbot, I enable events and tested the api-gateway url in slack

[slack app event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuG5u.png)

I'm failing to understand why there is no challenge nor token being sent in slack post to the api gateway URL
Besides the fact that I should be able to catch the challenge and return it to complete de verification process, there nothing being sent from slack challenge POST message (I should at least see the code:200 and the "Hello from Lambda!" message in the body anyway)

Following [this article](https://medium.com/glasswall-engineering/how-to-create-a-slack-bot-using-aws-lambda-in-1-hour-1dbc1b6f021c), I was expecting to see something like this, but mine has an empty response

[Slack Enable events from article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaUva.png)

Any clues? This is a new workspace and a new slack app, so it is possible that I forgot to set it correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you. I followed this example and got it to work: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-and-distribute-a-slack-bot-with-python-and-aws-in-1-hour-41c4a6c0f99d

The issue with my API was that initially I created an API in API Gateway of type REST. When I made an API of type HTTP, everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried with both HTTP and REST API gateways type. And neither work. But looking at my code again I realized that I was handling wrong the challenge response. Now it is working (and also for both HTTP and REST)
Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the medium post blog post that you shared. It was useful to identify the issue in the code